# Format output of Buffered writer string

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFile)));
buffWriter.write("\"time\",\"x voltage\", z voltage \n");
```

Later on, I call buffwriter.write again:

```
buffWriter.write("\"" + time[i] + "\",\"" + an_array[i] + "\", \"" + an_array2[i] + ",\n");
```

Everything is fine, except one really small thing. There is a " on the left side my an_array2 values. How do i get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using the following code

```
buffWriter.write("\"" + time[i] + "\",\"" + an_array[i] + "\", " + an_array2[i] + ",\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just giving you the answer, I'm going to suggest that you look carefully over your code to understand what it's doing. Let's split out your long string concatenation into multiple lines:

```
buffWriter.write("\""             // "
                 + time[i]        // (the time)
                 + "\",\""        // ","
                 + an_array[i]    // (array element)
                 + "\", \""       // ", "
                 + an_array2[i]   // (array element)
                 + ",\n");        // ,(line-break)
```

So yes, there's a " before your an_array2 values, because you've put it there in the bit that I've written as:

```
                 + "\", \""       // ", "
```

If you *just* want to close the previous quote and add a comma, you want:

```
                 + "\","
```

(You may or may not also want the space.)

Note that:

- This has nothing to do with `BufferedWriter` - you're just performing string concatenation
- This has nothing to do with Android really; it's just Java

It's important that you learn how to diagnose problems yourself, and that you understand every bit of your own code. Do you understand *why* `"\", \""` means "(double-quote) (comma) (space) (double-quote)"? If not, we can explain that in more detail (or you can read [section 3.10.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#101089)).